# HTML Purifier: Removing an element conditionally based on its attributes

Tags: php, html-parsing, htmlpurifier, html

As per [the HTML Purifier smoketest](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/smoketests/xssAttacks.php), 'malformed' URIs are occasionally discarded to leave behind an attribute-less anchor tag, e.g.

`<a href="javascript:document.location='http://www.google.com/'">XSS</a>` becomes `<a>XSS</a>`

...as well as occasionally being stripped down to the protocol, e.g.

`<a href="http://1113982867/">XSS</a>` becomes `<a href="http:/">XSS</a>`

While that's unproblematic, per se, it's a bit ugly. Instead of trying to strip these out with regular expressions, I was hoping to use HTML Purifier's own library capabilities / injectors / plug-ins / whathaveyou.

### Point of reference: Handling attributes

Conditionally removing an **attribute** in HTMLPurifier is easy. Here the library offers the class `HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform` with the method **`confiscateAttr()`**.

While I don't personally use the functionality of **`confiscateAttr()`**, I do use an `HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform` as per [this thread](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,4254) to add `target="_blank"` to all anchors.

```
// more configuration stuff up here
$htmlDef = $htmlPurifierConfiguration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$anchor  = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('a');
$anchor->attr_transform_post[] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_Target();
// purify down here
```

`HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_Target` is a very simple class, of course.

```
class HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_Target extends HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform
{
    public function transform($attr, $config, $context) {
        // I could call $this->confiscateAttr() here to throw away an
        // undesired attribute
        $attr['target'] = '_blank';
        return $attr;
    }
}
```

That part works like a charm, naturally.

### Handling elements

Perhaps I'm not squinting hard enough at `HTMLPurifier_TagTransform`, or am looking in the wrong place(s), or generally amn't understanding it, but I can't seem to figure out a way to conditionally remove **elements**.

Say, something to the effect of:

```
// more configuration stuff up here
$htmlDef = $htmlPurifierConfiguration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$anchor  = $htmlDef->addElementHandler('a');
$anchor->elem_transform_post[] = new HTMLPurifier_ElementTransform_Cull();
// add target as per 'point of reference' here
// purify down here
```

With the Cull class extending something that has a **`confiscateElement()`** ability, or comparable, wherein I could check for a missing `href` attribute or a `href` attribute with the content `http:/`.

### HTMLPurifier_Filter

I understand I could create a filter, but the examples (Youtube.php and ExtractStyleBlocks.php) suggest I'd be using regular expressions in that, which I'd really rather avoid, *if it is at all possible*. I'm hoping for an onboard or quasi-onboard solution that makes use of HTML Purifier's excellent parsing capabilities.

Returning `null` in a child-class of `HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform` unfortunately doesn't cut it.

Anyone have any smart ideas, or am I stuck with regexes? :)

Comment: I think I'm looking for the same thing ? look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646240/whitelist-element-with-class-of-using-htmlpurifier 

did you get this figured out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Success! Thanks to [Ambush Commander and mcgrailm in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646240/whitelist-element-with-class-of-using-htmlpurifier), I am now using a hilariously simple solution:

```
// a bit of context
$htmlDef = $this->configuration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$anchor  = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('a');

// HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_RemoveLoneHttp strips 'href="http:/"' from
// all anchor tags (see first post for class detail)
$anchor->attr_transform_post[] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_RemoveLoneHttp();

// this is the magic! We're making 'href' a required attribute (note the
// asterisk) - now HTML Purifier removes <a></a>, as well as
// <a href="http:/"></a> after HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_RemoveLoneHttp
// is through with it!
$htmlDef->addAttribute('a', 'href*', new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI());
```

It works, it *works*, bahahahaHAHAHAHAnhͥͤͫ̀ğͮ͑̆ͦó̓̉ͬ͋h́ͧ̆̈́̉ğ̈́͐̈a̾̈́̑ͨô̔̄̑̇g̀̄h̘̝͊̐ͩͥ̋ͤ͛g̦̣̙̙̒̀ͥ̐̔ͅo̤̣hg͓̈́͋̇̓́̆a͖̩̯̥͕͂̈̐ͮ̒o̶ͬ̽̀̍ͮ̾ͮ͢҉̩͉̘͓̙̦̩̹͍̹̠̕g̵̡͔̙͉̱̠̙̩͚͑ͥ̎̓͛̋͗̍̽͋͑̈́̚...**!** * manic laughter, gurgling noises, keels over with a smile on her face *

Comment: How do you make such *crazy* letters?

Comment: @MichalStefanow: http://www.eeemo.net/ - see also http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo ... and the stackoverflow-famous http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/245790

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you can't remove elements with a TagTransform appears to have been an implementation detail. The classic mechanism for removing *nodes* (a smidge higher-level than just tags) is to use an Injector though.

Anyway, the particular piece of functionality you're looking for is already implemented as %AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty

Comment: Arrrgh, so close! I changed my `HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_Target` class around so it wouldn't add `target="_blank"` to the cases I want to strip out (and for now, to test, in the same class, strip out `href="http:/"` if I come across it, will put that in its own class later), but `AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty` still doesn't fire because there's a text node in the anchor. If there's no text in it, it's gold, it works, so, argh, so close! Thank you so much, though, it was definitely something I hadn't thought of. [I'll take a look at injectors in a moment!]

Comment: Injectors loaded via `AutoFormat.Custom` seem to be called pre-purification, or at least pre-URI-purification - I'm not getting the empty tags there yet. Is there a way I can delay the call of the injector post-URI-purification?

Comment: What some other filters have done is forced the attribute validation before hand, and then armored the resulting token with $token->['ValidateAttributes'] = true

Comment: How would I force attribute validation beforehand? I mean, the instances of `<a></a>` and `<a href="http:/"></a>` are created by the core as far as I'm aware. Where would I tell it to do that before the injector?

Comment: Basically, you get an instance of HTMLPurifier_AttrValidator and then run $attr_validator->validateToken($token, $config, $context);.

Answer (score 1):

For perusal, this is my current solution. It works, but bypasses HTML Purifier entirely.

```
/**
 * Removes <a></a> and <a href="http:/"></a> tags from the purified
 * HTML.
 * @todo solve this with an injector?
 * @param string $purified The purified HTML
 * @return string The purified HTML, sans pointless anchors.
 */
private function anchorCull($purified)
{
    if (empty($purified)) return '';
    // re-parse HTML
    $domTree = new DOMDocument();
    $domTree->loadHTML($purified);
    // find all anchors (even good ones)
    $anchors = $domTree->getElementsByTagName('a');
    // collect bad anchors (destroying them in this loop breaks the DOM)
    $destroyNodes = array();
    for ($i = 0; ($i < $anchors->length); $i++) {
        $anchor = $anchors->item($i);
        $href   = $anchor->attributes->getNamedItem('href');
        // <a></a>
        if (is_null($href)) {
            $destroyNodes[] = $anchor;
        // <a href="http:/"></a>
        } else if ($href->nodeValue == 'http:/') {
            $destroyNodes[] = $anchor;
        }
    }
    // destroy the collected nodes
    foreach ($destroyNodes as $node) {
        // preserve content
        $retain = $node->childNodes;
        for ($i = 0; ($i < $retain->length); $i++) {
            $rnode = $retain->item($i);
            $node->parentNode->insertBefore($rnode, $node);
        }
        // actually destroy the node
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    // strip out HTML out of DOM structure string
    $html = $domTree->saveHTML();
    $begin = strpos($html, '<body>') + strlen('<body>');
    $end   = strpos($html, '</body>');
    return substr($html, $begin, $end - $begin);
}
```

I'd still much rather have a good HTML Purifier solution to this, so, just as a heads-up, this answer won't end up self-accepted. But in case no better answer ends up coming around, at least it might help those with similar issues. :)