# HTML Purifier strip elements with a certain attribute

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

Is there anyway to make HTML Purifier strip elements with a certain attribute.

I'm using HTML Purifier to clean up a full webpage into just its basic content so I can index and search it.

I want to be able to add an attribute like `data-no-index` to some wrapper to make them ignored.

This is my HTML Purifier setup:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,a[href],ul,ol,li,img[src]');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Comment: I have never used Purifier before, but could you just add `tagname[data-no-index]` to your allowed list?

Comment: @scrowler I want to deny it, not allow it.

Comment: ok, how about the `ForbiddenAttributes` option? `$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenAttributes', array('tagname.data-no-index'));` - docs: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.ForbiddenAttributes

Comment: To be clear, you want the entire element to be removed when the attribute exists?

Comment: Petah, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638640/html-purifier-removing-an-element-conditionally-based-on-its-attributes (...I guess this is even technically a duplicate, oops. XD)

Comment: You'll have to do some coding to implement this. There are a few implementation strategies I can think of but nothing out of the box.