# htmlpurifier allow scheme for specific tags

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true, 'http' => true));

$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array(
    'a', 'img'
));

$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', array(
    'a.href', 'img.src'
));
```

I have a htmlpurifier config like above. I want `URI.AllowedSchemes` to apply a specific html tag. For example `img` tag can only have data and `a` tag can only have http. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with configuration, but you can write your own attribute handling class(es) for `img` and `a`. Maybe check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638640/html-purifier-removing-an-element-conditionally-based-on-its-attributes and see if that helps you? (I'm only commenting and not answering because this is a pretty half-assed answer, but I hope it helps you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution;

Filters;

```
class ImgSrcTransform extends HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform
{
    protected $parse;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->parser = new HTMLPurifier_URIParser();
    }
    public function transform($attr, $config, $context)
    {
        if(!isset($attr['src'])){
            return $attr;
        }

        $url = $this->parser->parse($attr['src']);
        if($url->scheme == 'http' || $url->scheme == 'https'){
            unset($attr['src']);
        }

        return $attr;
    }
}

class LinkHrefTransform extends HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform
{
    protected $parse;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->parser = new HTMLPurifier_URIParser();
    }
    public function transform($attr, $config, $context)
    {
        if(!isset($attr['href'])){
            return $attr;
        }

        $url = $this->parser->parse($attr['href']);


        if($url->scheme == 'data'){
            unset($attr['href']);
        }

        return $attr;
    }
}
```

Using the filters;

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true, 'http' => true, 'https' => true));
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', $elements);
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', $attributes);

$htmlDef = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);

$img = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('img');
$img->attr_transform_pre[] = new ImgSrcTransform();

$anchor = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('a');
$anchor->attr_transform_pre[] = new LinkHrefTransform();

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```